# Predicting from previous date:value data

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, prediction

I have a few data sets from similar periods of time. It's a presentation of people at that day, the period being about a year. The data hasn't been gathered in regular intervals, it is rather quite random: 15-30 entries for each year, from 5 different years.

The graph drawn from the data for each year looks roughly like this:
[image: graph]
Graph made with matplotlib.
I have the data in `datetime.datetime, int` format.

Is it possible to predict, in any sensible way, how things will turn out in the future? My original thought was to count the average from all previous occurrences and predict it will be this. That, though, doesn't take in consideration any data from the current year (if it has been higher than average all the time, the guess should probably be slightly higher).

The data set and my knowledge of statistics is limited, so every insight is helpful.

My goal would be to first create a prototype solution, to try out if my data is enough for what I'm trying to do and after the (potential) validation, I would try a more refined approach.

Edit: Unfortunately I never had the chance to try the answers I received! I'm still curious though if that kind of data would be enough and will keep this in mind if I ever get the chance. Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: this question isnt really about code, more about math, how do you define prediction in this sense? and what is the mathematical way on this type of curve/graph ? i dont think this is the right place for this question.

Comment: @Inbar I'm aware that this doesn't perfectly fit the code section, but it is the only angle I'm approaching this from. I trust that people here have enough expertise to give me a direction for the solution.

Comment: This question would be a better fit on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 13):

In your case, the data is changing fast, and you have immediate observations of new data. A quick prediction can be implemented using [Holt-winter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) exponential smoothing.

The update equations:

[image]

`m_t` is the data you have, e.g., the number of people at each time `t`. `v_t` is the first derivative, i.e., the trending of `m`. `alpha` and `beta` are two decay parameters. The variable with `tilde` on top denotes the predicted value. Check the details of the algorithm at the wikipedia page.

Since you use `python`, I can show you some example code to help you with the data. BTW, I use some synthetic data as below:

```
data_t = range(15)
data_y = [5,6,15,20,21,22,26,42,45,60,55,58,55,50,49]
```

Above `data_t` is a sequence of consecutive data points starting at time 0; `data_y` is a sequence of observed number of people at each presentation.

The data looks like below ( I tried to make it close to your data).

[image]

The code for the algorithm is straightforward.

```
def holt_alg(h, y_last, y_pred, T_pred, alpha, beta):
    pred_y_new = alpha * y_last + (1-alpha) * (y_pred + T_pred * h)
    pred_T_new = beta * (pred_y_new - y_pred)/h + (1-beta)*T_pred
    return (pred_y_new, pred_T_new)

def smoothing(t, y, alpha, beta):
    # initialization using the first two observations
    pred_y = y[1]
    pred_T = (y[1] - y[0])/(t[1]-t[0])
    y_hat = [y[0], y[1]]
    # next unit time point
    t.append(t[-1]+1)
    for i in range(2, len(t)):
        h = t[i] - t[i-1]
        pred_y, pred_T = holt_alg(h, y[i-1], pred_y, pred_T, alpha, beta)
        y_hat.append(pred_y)
    return y_hat
```

Ok, now let's call our predictor and plot the predicted result against the observations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data_t, data_y, 'x-')
plt.hold(True)

pred_y = smoothing(data_t, data_y, alpha=.8, beta=.5)
plt.plot(data_t[:len(pred_y)], pred_y, 'rx-')
plt.show()
```

The red shows the prediction result at each time point. I set `alpha` to be 0.8, so that the most recent observation does affect the next prediction a lot. If you want to give history data more weight, just play with the parameters `alpha` and `beta`. Also note, the right-most data point on red-line at `t=15` is the last prediction, at which we do not have an observation yet.

BTW, [this](https://gist.github.com/126ec1249d0bb9ed3ef2) is far from a perfect prediction. It's just something you can start with quickly. One of the cons of this approach is that you have to be able to get observations, otherwise the prediction would be off more and more (probably this is true for all real-time predictions). Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Prediction is hard. You might want to try [**polynomial extrapolation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation) - but the estimation **mistake will increase drastically as you get farther from the "known" area**.

Another possible solution is trying to use [**machine learning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) algorithms, but it requires you gathering a lot of data.

Extract features from your data (a feature is the number of entries in a single day, for example). And train the algorithm. (Give it a far past data a features, and the present as the predicted field, for example).

I do not know about python, but in java - there is an open source library called [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) that implements most of the functionalities and algorithm used for machine learning.

You can estimate how accurate this method is using [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) later on.

---

With that said - this problem is usually referred as trend detection, and is a hot field in research currently, so [there is no silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

Comment: Does machine learning really need a lot of data? I mean, for things like linear regression, it might not (I've only done a little, so I'm basically asking)

Comment: @darkphoenix: From personal experience - the more data you have - the better results the algorithm will get. Also, to prove it actually work - you do it with statistical tests. These usually require hundreds or thousands of classified instances..

Comment: For python, there is scikits.learn, I believe you can use orange as well. Both depend on numpy.