# How to estimate next values on Matlab

Tags: matlab, prediction, kalman-filter

I have a vector of values corresponding to the measured data and I want to predict the next values. How can I do that? I know that is possible with Kalman filter but it might be an easier way to do. Here is a plot of the data and I want to predict next values:
[image: Measured data]

Comment: It depends upon the nature of your data. You should try to model your data with connection of its meaning. To give you some clue: A would be a transition matrix and its values are related to the transition from the previous state. Its values would be different if your data coming from some market where you model next value with different factors. Values of A would be different if your data coming from electric sensor measuring AC current. Similarly H is a matrix of state measurement and if your data comes from the market you probably read what you get and value is 1 but not in sensor case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing), e.g., double exponential smoothing or Holt-Winters method. Basically you try to learn the trend of the data.

I have some sample `python` code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845055/predicting-from-previous-datevalue-data/13409899#13409899) post.

On the other hand, if you know the movement/observation model of the underline variable, for sure, kalman will give you much better predictions as @tomasz74 pointed out.

Comment: Is there a place to read the math behind it?